# Google OAuth, get only email and no plus related data

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-plus, google-oauth

When my application authenticates users using their google account, I use scope as "email", but for some reason, google still tells them that my app can see "who you are on google". Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant change how the Authentication screen.  It displays what it does depending upon what scopes you send.

Just be sure that you are only sending the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`. If you are then it may be that `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` automatically includes the permissions `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me` but I am not seeing anything in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#scopes) that states that.  I would have to test.

Comment: Thanks, I was asking about scope itself. I tried userinfo.email but that also includes plus.me

Comment: Yeah you cant really change that.  the email one is the only option for you really.   And it seams it includes plus.me by default. which almost makes sense because you have to know who you are to know your email